# LEFT JOIN issue in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables **Movie** and **timing** and i want to show its data.here is my query

```
SELECT m.title,
       t.timing 
FROM Movie AS m 
LEFT JOIN timing AS t 
ON m.id=t.movie_id and t.cenema like '%Dubai Mall%'
```

Movie

1   | LUCKY

2   | EXP

Timing

Id   |  Cenema | movie_id | timing

1    |  Dubai Mall | 1|..

2    | Dubai Mall  | 1   |..

For one movie i have two records in timing so it give me duplicate result.

How i can avoid?

Comment: Yes you will get 2 records if there are 2 records in the joining table.. One way to use `group by`

Comment: what's t.timing in your query ? you have no column timing in timing table...

Comment: could you please list expected result that your are looking for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html

Use distinct.

or use group by

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` can be used to filter out duplicates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ... <rest of your query>
```

"The SELECT DISTINCT statement is used to return only distinct (different) values."  [w3schools - DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You have to have

```
GROUP BY m.id
```

this way mysql knows to group the results by the movie ID to each line all query will look like:

```
SELECT m.title,t.timing FROM Movie AS m LEFT JOIN timing AS t 
ON m.id=t.movie_id and t.cenema like '%Dubai Mall%' GROUP BY m.id
```